# Get values of custom fields of a custom object using DescribeResult

Tags: apex, sobject

I have a custom object Custom__c and I am accessing its fields by using

```
Public Custom__c custom1 {get;set;}

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> map = Schema.SObjectType.Custom1__c.fields.getMap();
for(String fieldName : map.keySet()) {
    //using the fields for some processing using custom1
    this.custom1 = [select fieldName from Custom1 where.....];
}
```

Then I create another object for Custom__c

```
 Custom__c custom2 = new Custom__c();
```

Now what I want to do is assign the custom fields of custom2 the values of custom fields of custom1.

```
 for(String fieldName : map.keySet()) {
     value of fieldName of custom2 = value of fieldName of custom1
 }
```

I am not sure how to achieve this. All I know is it can be (?) done using DescribeResult, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the field name tokens using describe and then iterate over the keySet to set the values on Custom2 from Custom 1.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Custom__c.fields.getMap();

For(string fName : M.keySet())
Custom2.put(fName, Custom1.get(fName));
```